instance on points - selection - regular indices
Is it possible to distribute the instances on points with selection, but still keep the instance index row order on these selected points without altering the curve geometry (I am sampling the instance attributes later to change the same curve geometry)?



accumulate the boolean as integer, then use the leading as instance index.

solved, thanks!

The best way to post the solution is to write an answer below your own post. And no need to credit me. :)

solution from the comments above:

